# Have search using foreach loop not return on first match

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach, frameworks

I want to get all records with the same `refid` but my `foreach` loop is just searching until it find the first record and halts.

```
$data = Projekt1Db::select('refid', 'userid', 'passwd', 'uid', 'gid', 'homedir')->get();
        $inputs = \Request::all();
        foreach ($data as $id) {
            if ($id->refid == $inputs['refid']){
                return view('searchfound', [
                    'id' => $id]);
            }
        }

        if($inputs !== $id){
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Refid not found');
        }
    }
```

There are more records with the same `refid`, but it just gives me the first record with that `refid`.

In the view:

```
<b>Refid:</b> {{$id->refid}}<br>
<b>Userid:</b> {{$id->userid}}<br>
<b>Password:</b> {{$id->passwd}}<br>
<b>UID:</b> {{$id->uid}}<br>
<b>GID:</b> {{$id->gid}}<br>
<b>homedir:</b> {{$id->homedir}}<br><br>
```

Comment: $data=Projekt1Db::where('refid','=', $inputs->refid);,then you can loop easily right

Comment: also in you are answer you are getting first record because of you are returning value.instead of return store in array like how others are given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below for your php code:

```
            $data = Projekt1Db::select('refid', 'userid', 'passwd', 'uid', 'gid', 'homedir')->get();
            $inputs = Request::all();

            $id_array = [];
            foreach ($data as $id) {
                if ($id->refid == $inputs['refid']){
                    $id_array[] = $id;
                }
            }

           if(count($id_array) == 0){
             return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Refid not found');
           }
            else{
              return view('searchfound', ['id' => $id_array]);  
            }
```

and the layout code below:

```
@foreach($id as $val)
  <b>Refid:</b> {{$val->refid}}<br>
  <b>Userid:</b> {{$val->userid}}<br>
  <b>Password:</b> {{$val->passwd}}<br>
  <b>UID:</b> {{$val->uid}}<br>
  <b>GID:</b> {{$val->gid}}<br>
  <b>homedir:</b> {{$val->homedir}}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) but it still doesnt find something

Comment: i dont know how to explain the current problem... maybe this helps you: Trying to get property of non-object - said laravel - I'm really sorry for my english :)

Comment: i know but it says that id is still undefined :o :/

Comment: I updated my answer and where is the error being thrown in the php code or layout code

Comment: so now it says that in the layout code i'm trying  to get property of non-object :o

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($data as $id) {
     if ($id->refid == $inputs['refid']){
            $newData[] = $id;
     }
}
 return view('searchfound', [
                'newData' => $newData]);

@foreach($newData as $val)
  <b>Refid:</b> {{$val->refid}}<br>
  <b>Userid:</b> {{$val->userid}}<br>
  <b>Password:</b> {{$val->passwd}}<br>
  <b>UID:</b> {{$val->uid}}<br>
  <b>GID:</b> {{$val->gid}}<br>
  <b>homedir:</b> {{$val->homedir}}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: doesnt work :/ it just gives me 4 times the same record.. but i want any diferent record with the same refid :/

Comment: this code havent any connection with my DB and i dont know what i should do with my redirect->back()

Comment: Can you `print_r($data);`?

Comment: Can you post the result data?

Comment: i cant :o i'm not allowed to show you what in $data is... i'm in my office and there are things i cant show :o

Comment: Just the the array structure and dummy data

Answer (score 0):

Basic, change

```
foreach ($data as $id) {
  if ($id->refid == $inputs['refid']){
    return view('searchfound', [
      'id' => $id]);
  }
}
```

to

```
$data = array();        
foreach ($data as $id) {
  if ($id->refid == $inputs['refid']){
    $data[] = $id;
  }
}
if (length($data) > 0) {
  var_dump($data);
} else {
  // nothing found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use where condition if you have many records of same refidid

```
    $data=Projekt1Db::where('refid','=', $inputs->refid);

foreach ($data as $id) {


}
```

then you can loop easily right